# How to do file output for a long-running program

Tags: c++, file-io

I write a simulation program. In each time step, it writes a block of output into a file. It's still under development, therefore it will crash or get terminated by the user sometimes. In that case, for debugging and analysis, I'd still like to have my file in a correct state, containing the data that was already written.

Currently, I do the following:

**Upon start of the program,** I open the file non-appending and close it right away, just to empty the file:

```
file.open(fname, std::ios::binary);
file.close();
```

**On each time step**, I first open the file appending, write the data, and close the file:

```
file.open(fname, std::ios::binary | std::ios::app);
... // data is written here
file.close();
```

**Is that a good way to solve the problem or do you recommend a different approach?**

Comment: your code already keeps the file with the data you already had written to it.

Comment: if the program crashes, why not use exception handling so the file will close before the program will terminate?

Comment: Interesting and hard question. The OS will close the file when the app crashes. Closing it manually probably doesn't make a difference. For starters, what's your OS?

Comment: @ZachiShtain: If the program crashes, then there is no more exception handling. And if the exception handling happens before the crash, then the destructor of `std::ofstream` will make sure that the file is closed.

Comment: Instead of `open` with `app` and `close` - why not simply use `flush` instead?

Answer (score -1):

No, that method wastes a lot of time.

Have you tried to write signal handlers to clean up properly? You can handle most things like the user pressing Control-C and close the file before quitting.

Another idea is to turn off buffering. The easiest way to do this may be just to redirect STDERR to your file, as that is unbuffered by default.